# How do I display a specific JSON value with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a simple [JSON file](https://jsonblob.com/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c) with a "customers" object.

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "account": "123456",
      "amount": "$121.34",
      "period": "13th July - 13th August",
      "duedate": "14th September"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Jack",
      "lastname": "Bauer",
      "account": "1111222",
      "amount": "$142.56",
      "period": "11th July - 11th August",
      "duedate": "16th September"
    }
  ]
}
```

Essentially, when a customer visits the page, I want to display his own personal information using Angular JS. So, something like below:

```
<h2>{{ customers.amount[0] }}</h2>
<p>{{ customers.period[0] }}</p>
<p>{{ customers.duedate[0] }}</p>
```

my JS file is:

```
var UtilityApp = angular.module('UtilityApp', []);

UtilityApp.config(['$qProvider', function($qProvider) {
     $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
 }]);

UtilityApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://jsonblob.com/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c'
 }).then(function (data) {

    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.customers = data.customers;

  }), function () {
    return "Error";
  }

});
```

1. How can I return all information for customer 1, then customer 2...? Would ng-repeat with a filter be a better approach?
2. What is a better way to ensure that a customer is looking at his information (and not someone else)? I don't want to use a login here, so I was thinking using a specific URL to visit for customer. Any better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it using both ways ..but you should have an unique identifier to filter.so in your case which is the unique identifier to identify which customer data belong to logged in customer from the customer array.Or else you can simply do ng-repeat to show all your data.

Comment: as @NamdeoKarande said, you need a unique identifier to show particular person's data.

Answer (score 2):

Best and most efficient way would be to get single customer from backend API, so you can ensure security and response is smaller because you don't need to fetch all customers, but if you can't get only one customer then
better would be to filter customer in controller by some key (id, cookie, account etc.)

```
UtilityApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://jsonblob.com/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c'
 }).then(function (data) {

    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.accountId = 'getItSomehow';
    $scope.currentCustomer = data.customers.find(x => x.account === $scope.accountId);


  }), function () {
    return "Error";
  }

});


<h2>{{ currentCustomer.amount }}</h2>
<p>{{ currentCustomer.period }}</p>
<p>{{ currentCustomer.duedate }}</p>
```

ng-repeat with filter would be slowest and vague, don't do it.

Note: have a look at array .find https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find because it is not supported in old browsers.

Comment: `Array.prototype.find()` is not supported in all browser. So it would be better to use some other methods like `filter()`

Comment: You can add Polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. Filter is not optimal solution because you need to iterate with all array items.

Comment: yes I know.So if possible mention that in your answer.

Comment: Your approach seems to be the right one, but I can't get it working - see Fiddle: [https://fiddle.jshell.net/su1att9s/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/su1att9s/). What am I missing?

Comment: I see errors in fiddle Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined, you need to import angular library.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the wrong `URL` for requesting the json data from json blob. Make the correct url as `https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c` i.e. `https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/<blobId>`.

It will return the `JSON` data containing customers array then you can use the simple `ng-repeat` to show the data for both customers. or can extract specific data for the single customers reading the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your customer information like a table using flex or the `<table>` tag.

If you want to see the information of your customers you should change your code to this.

```
<h2>{{ customers.amount[0] }}</h2> // <h2>{{ customers[0].amount }}</h2>
<p>{{ customers.period[0] }}</p>   // <p>{{ customers[0].period }}</p>
<p>{{ customers.duedate[0] }}</p>  // <p>{{ customers[0].duedate }}</p>
```

Or using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <h2>{{ customer.amount }}</h2>
    <p>{{ customer.period }}</p>
    <p>{{ customer.duedate }}</p>
</div>
```

But if you want to see the information of a specific customer you should pass an ID as a param in the URL for example wit ui-router.

To get the information of the second customer. Example:

```
http://www.exampleweb.com/customer/2
```

check out the ui-router module.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the URL of http request from `https://jsonblob.com/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c` to `https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c`.

Also, I have modified the response object. It have data object which contains your customers object.

You can use some filter condition to identify the customer.

```js
var UtilityApp = angular.module('UtilityApp', []);

UtilityApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c'
 }).then(function (response) {
    $scope.customers = response["data"]["customers"];
    //Logic to identify the customer and then bind to $scope.currentCustomer
    $scope.account = "123456";
    $scope.currentCustomer = response.data.customers.find(x => x.account === $scope.account);
    
  }, function () {
    return "Error";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="UtilityApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>Customer's Info</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>Account : {{ currentCustomer.account }}</h2>
    <p>Amount : {{ currentCustomer.amount }}</p>
    <p>Period : {{ currentCustomer.period }}</p>
    <p>DueDate : {{ currentCustomer.due_date }}</p>
  </div>
  
  
  <h1>Binding all customer using ng-repeat </h1>
  <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <h2>{{ customer.amount }}</h2>
    <p>{{ customer.period }}</p>
    <p>{{ customer.due_date }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As mentioned above, doing an ng-repeat on a large data set to fetch a single information might be counter-productive...

Comment: I was using ng-repeat to bind all customer, it was just for demonstration. I have updated my solution to display the customer whose account no is `123456`. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want display one particular user at a time then dont use ng-repeat. Simply filter the response data or create a service at server side which give response for particular use by pass parameter.
For now you can filter response

```
 var UtilityApp = angular.module('UtilityApp', []);

 UtilityApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
            $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
        }
    ]);

 UtilityApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.customerAccountId = "123456";
    $scope.currentCustomer = null;
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'https://jsonblob.com/26078b70-6b6f-11e7-a38a-bf689f57642c'
    }).then(function (data) {

        $scope.customers = data.customers;
        $scope.currentCustomer = $(x) => {
            return x.account === $scope.customerAccountId
        };

    }),
    function () {
        return "Error";
    }

 });
```

And Display **currentCustomer** details :

```
<div>
  <p>{{ currentCustomer.amount }}</p>
  <p>{{ currentCustomer.period }}</p>
  <p>{{ currentCustomer.duedate }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//html
<div ng-repeat="obj in customers track by $index">
   <h2>{{ obj.amount }}</h2>
   <p>{{ obj.period }}</p>
   <p>{{ obj.duedate }}</p>
</div>

//controller
$scope.customers = [
   {
     "firstname": "John",
     "lastname": "Doe",
     "account": "123456",
     "amount": "$121.34",
     "period": "13th July - 13th August",
     "duedate": "14th September"
   },
   {
      "firstname": "Jack",
      "lastname": "Bauer",
      "account": "1111222",
      "amount": "$142.56",
      "period": "11th July - 11th August",
      "duedate": "16th September"
   }
];
```